# vba get value from sql server recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

My code to retrieve value is as below:

```
Sub UploadData()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim strConn As String
Dim sql As String

strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=.\sql2000;INITIAL CATALOG=EquityDB;INTEGRATED    SECURITY=sspi;"

cn.Open strConn

sql = "select * from  EquityDB.dbo.table1 where field1 = '" & Replace(Range("d1").Value, "'", "''") & "'"

 rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
  GetData = rs.Fields(0).Value


 If Not GetData = "" Then

 cn.Execute sql001

 Else

 cn.Execute sql002

End If
```

sql001 is an insert, and sql002 is an update

When I run the macro, I got error saying operation is not allowed when the record is open for the line

```
    rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

If I change

```
   If Not GetData = "" Then
```

to

```
   If Not GetData Is Null Then
```

I get error saying "object required" with the line

```
   If Not GetData Is Null Then
```

Any advice on how to fix the bug would be great!

Comment: 1) What is the actual error you are getting and which line is causing it? 2) it should be `If Not IsEmpty(GetData) then`

Comment: Also explain what you are trying to achieve. Create a new record when no record is found and updating the record or records when it is\they are found? My guess is that the update part goes wrong.

Comment: The VBA command to test for null is IsNull(Object).

Comment: Thanks for all of your advice! I was actually trying to do a loop, I guess I just need to clear the rs each time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test if anything was returned into your recordset, instead of:

```
 GetData = rs.Fields(0).Value    

 If Not GetData = "" Then
```

Use:

```
If not(rs.eof and rs.bof) then
```

This will return true if the recordset is not empty.